# Xcode Parse login screen fields

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

Im looking for a solution to change the login fields on Parse, but i can't figure out why im getting a error :

> Property 'logInView' not found on Object type : FrontViewController

My code are :

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grå-baggrund-pattern-50.jpg"]]];

    [self.loginView setTitle:@"Some text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.logInView signUpButton setTitle:@"Some text" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: What is `FrontViewController`, how is it defined?

Comment: My FrontViewController are a :@interface FrontViewController : UIViewController <PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate>

Answer (score 0):

Your class is a delegate for a login or a signup view controller, so it has a hand in managing the views but it doesn't own them, so you don't have direct reference to the view. Hence the property you're trying to use doesn't exist.

You should be creating and displaying a login or signup view controller and accessing it's view to change the required properties.